# Simplest way to send short messages using TCP/IP

Tags: embedded, tcp

I typically use hardwired serial port connections between embedded devices for custom command/response/status protocols.
In this application I plan to use the microchip TCP/IP stack and Wi-Fi module *with no OS* to exchange short (<= 100 byte) commands and responses.
The stack is up and running on a microchip ethernet development kit and I am able to ping it from my desktop (not using the Wi-Fi module just yet).
I suppose I could hack into ping (microchip provides the c source for the stack) and add the messages I need to it, but I am looking for the correct/simplest/best method.

Comment: What hardware/kit are you using out of curiosity. as Im also interested in doing something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct / simplest / best aren't necessarily the same thing.  But if I were you, I would consider using UDP instead of TCP.

UDP is a datagram protocol; TCP is stream-oriented and has a lot more overhead (and benefits that come with the overhead).  But UDP more closely matches the current serial port byte-oriented (packet-oriented) approach you have today.

Chances are you have some higher-level protocol that receives/buffers/checksums/delimits/parses the data stream you receive from the UART.  If you use UDP, you can mimic this nicely with a lean, lightweight UDP implementation.  With UDP you just shoot out the bytes (packets) & cross your fingers that they got to the other end (a lot like serial).

TCP is heavier-weight connection-based protocol with built-in resending, acknowledgments, in-order delivery, timers, back-off algorithms, etc.  On most embedded systems I've worked with using TCP (several different stacks), UDP is lighter-weight & outperforms TCP in terms of code size & throughput.

Also don't forget that TCP is used as the backbone of the internet; some packets pass through a dozen or more hops (routers/gateways) en route to the final destination.  Lots of places for packets to get dropped, so TCP handles a lot of messy details transparently.  I'd guess in your system/situation, we're talking about a LAN (everyone on the same wire) and transmission will be pretty reliable... thus the TCP overhead isn't really necessary.

There are times when the benefits of TCP justify the overhead, but from what you've written I think you should consider a basic UDP datagram set up.  Just google "simple udp example" and you'll see the basic structure.  For example, [here is a simple UDP client/server example](http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html) using just 43 lines (server) and 30 lines (client).

Comment: Somewhat mistaken answer.  UDP's risk of packet drop and out of order delivery is substantially different from normal conditions on a serial line, which TCP much more closely emulates.  The primary problems with TCP are statefull connection (getting reconnection implemented correctly), and the hard-to-disable nagle ack delay on the client PC end which can insert 200ms delays in query/response communication.  If you can't tolerate that then implementing your own reliability layer on top of UDP is worth the trouble; if you can, TCP will be a more direct drop-in replacement for serial.

Comment: @Chris on a switched network at reasonable load UDP will be fine. A simple ACK packet will cover 99% of cases Jack needs.  Large installed base of product, worldwide. Also tolerates radio links better.

Comment: You must not make the mistake of designing around an assumption which the underlying protocol explicitly does not guarantee.  If you are going to use UDP, you must be able to recover from missing and misordered packets - no matter how unlikely they may seem on your test network.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a TCP/IP stack, it should provide a send() function to send some data messages.

Some small devices come only with a simple UDP/IP implementation, since this is a lot simpler. If you don't need the sequence control and reliability of TCP you could consider to use UDP to send short messages. This is much better to hack the ICMP messages.

But if you need the comfort and reliabilty of the TCP stream protocol, dont re-invent this on base of IUDP. Usually you can't do it better, more efficient and with less effort.